# Searching in google using GET method

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-search

I want to query google using GET method and retrieve the HTML result. I've tried the following:

```
import httplib
import urllib

params = urllib.urlencode({'gws_rd': 'ssl', 'q': 'hello'})  # search for hello
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/plain"}
c = httplib.HTTPSConnection("google.com")
c.request("GET", "/", params, headers)
response = c.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
data = response.read()
file_ = open('result.html', 'w')
file_.write(data)
file_.close()
```

But I get this error:

> 400 Bad Request

Anybody knows how I can fix this?

Comment: You may need to change the User Agent header.

Comment: btw, it is against Google's t&c.. ;)

Comment: @SugatoSengupta If google allowed me to use their search API (which is not available in my country), their t&c would matter to me :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi what you trying to do is already Deprecated. You can check below link for the reference.

https://developers.google.com/web-search/

In place of that google have given new API.

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Above link will give you Full information how to work with it.

You have to create a key and need to change you code little to make it work.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I am trying to use the deprecated method because Google APIs are not available in my country.

Comment: If you want you can use DUCKDUCKGO search engine and its API in place of google. This is the api link for it http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=search_data&format=json&pretty=1